# SVG rendering incomplete in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I've been searching for a few hours for a reason this SVG wouldn't work in Firefox. Anyone know if I'm running into a known bug or have a problem in my code here?

http://codepen.io/ryanburnette/pen/c5274e0076748da1a53a2d16c8702050

I'm asking specifically in terms of the SVG in that Pen. Note my code is in Slim here.

```
svg.overlay viewbox="0 0 265 281.551" 
  g
    path.outer d="M132.5,0C59.322,0,0,59.322,0,132.5c0,66.245,48.616,121.134,112.115,130.939l16.505,16.504, c2.143,2.144,5.617,2.144,7.762-0.001l0.001,0.001l16.504-16.505C216.385,253.633,265,198.745,265,132.5,C265,59.322,205.678,0,132.5,0z"
    path.inner d="M132.502,256.388C64.08,256.388,8.614,200.921,8.614,132.5S64.08,8.612,132.502,8.612,c68.421,0,123.887,55.467,123.887,123.888S200.923,256.388,132.502,256.388z"
```

**Update 1:**

I had commas where I shouldn't have. What's interesting is that Firefox was the only browser in which the malformed SVG didn't work properly in spite of the error. Specifically, in Firefox, the element did not render past the point where the comma which should not have been there was located.

**Update 2:**

As validation has been suggested to me I tried validating my SVG markup using the W3C markup validation service. While this does check the integrity of the XML, it wouldn't have caught this particular problem.

Comment: I've tried adding height/width and it made no difference.

Comment: So Firefox is the only browser precisely following the SVG specification. i.e. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF and http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ErrorProcessing

Comment: Interesting info! I wonder if I could have used a validation tool to have solved this issue. Would the W3C Validator have caught that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added extra commas `,` in your path. You need to remove them.

### Updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/dPoqYz)

```
path.outer d="M132.5,0 C59.322,0 0,59.322 0,132.5 c0,66.245 48.616,121.134 112.115,130.939 l16.505,16.504 c2.143,2.144 5.617,2.144 7.762-0.001 l0.001,0.001 l16.504-16.505C216.385,253.633 265,198.745 265,132.5 C265,59.322 205.678,0 132.5,0z"
path.inner d="M132.502,256.388C64.08 256.388,8.614 200.921,8.614 132.5S64.08,8.612 132.502,8.612 c68.421,0 123.887,55.467 123.887,123.888 S200.923,256.388 132.502,256.388z"
```

Comment: And suddenly it's obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your path is invalid per the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF). Specifically commas are only allowed **between** numbers i.e. `...l16.505,16.504, c2.143,2.144,5.617...` is an [error](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/implnote.html#ErrorProcessing).

Comment: I see. Would `\n` be appropriate in that case?

Comment: A space or indeed nothing at all would be fine.

Comment: This helped me understand SVG and the issue more clearly. Thanks!